# "to this end", "for this purpose", etc. in the end of a sentence

Tags: word-order

I'm sure that one may say:

> *For this purpose* you can use a hammer.

But may one change the word order?

> You can use a hammer *for this purpose*

(my uncertainty is caused by Google)

Comment: Yes, either order is perfectly acceptable.  In fact, I think the second one actually sounds better, maybe because it begins with the subject and verb rather than with the conjunction or preposition.

Comment: @stangdon, I think your comment is exhastive. Why not make it an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, either order is perfectly acceptable.

In fact, I think the second one actually sounds better, maybe because it begins with the subject and verb ("You can use") rather than with the conjunction or preposition ("for this purpose").  This emphasizes the subject instead of the explanatory phrase.